# Docplex vs CPLEX Python API

Tags: cplex, docplex

What is the difference between Docplex and CPLEX Python API? Is any of them faster than the other?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [CPLEX Python API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex.Cplex-class.html) is a lightweight wrapper around the [C API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/homepageCrefman.html) (aka, the C Callable Library). As such, it provides access to nearly all of the functionality CPLEX has to offer. Variables and constraints are identified by their indices in the matrix.

[docplex](https://cdn.rawgit.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-doc/master/docs/index.html) is an object oriented modeling API that is numpy/pandas friendly, which may be more natural to work with. The model can be solved locally (using the CPLEX Python API under the hood), or on the cloud. In addition to providing access to CPLEX for mathematical programming, it can also be used to access the [CP Optimizer](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cpo.help/CP_Optimizer/topics/cpo_KC_home.html) constraint programming engine.

It is usually faster to build the model directly with the CPLEX Python API as it is a lower-level API. However, docplex can take care of some of the intricacies of getting the best performance when building a model while only incurring a relatively low overhead. The actual solve time should be more or less identical.

Comment: Can you explain what is the pros of "In addition to providing access to CPLEX for mathematical programming, it can also be used to access the CP Optimizer constraint programming engine", as I don't understand the need nor the use of CP Optimizer when we have access to CPLEX Python API.