# Documents and Syntax Reference for docplex

Tags: python-3.x, cplex, docplex

I was wondering if anyone could guide me to obtain a kind of document that specifically contains all syntax of CPLEX library on Python 2.7.  and probably an example to show the arguments.
The syntax I am looking for is that I need to see just one or a range of constraints, but the following command presents all the model:

```
print(mdl.export_to_string())
```

I need to only see constraints e.g. in range 10 to 20. 
Thanks,

Comment: Just to clarify it looks like you are using docplex rather than the CPLEX Python API. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891266) stackoverflow question for details on the differences.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to export only a certain part of the model. However, if you use the [Model.export_to_stream](http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/docplex.mp.model.html#docplex.mp.model.Model.export_to_stream) method you could potentially filter out the constraints you are interested in based on the naming pattern of your constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `docplex.mp.model.Model` is at http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/docplex.mp.model.html.  And the rest of the documentation is available from http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/.

Comment: Since this is unrelated to the original question and code formatting is not done properly in comments, I suggest you start a new question.

Comment: Also note that in a Python shell you can use the `help` function to get the reference documentation for all docplex classes.