# CPLEX Python API how to multiply a decision variable with a dummy in the objective function?

Tags: python, linear-programming, cplex

I am trying to add a multiplication of variables to the objective function. I have x_t which is an integer and I have a binary variable w_t_1. I want to have in the objective function -1200 * w_t_1 * x_t. How can I do it? I couldn't find anything in the IBM documentation.

Comment: Are you using the CPLEX Python API or docplex? You mention the former in the title, but it's not clear from the rest of your question whether that is really the case or not. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891266 for more on the difference.

Comment: I am using the Python API, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

let me give you a very simple example out of the [zoo example](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/)

```
mdl.maximize(nbbus40*500*option1+nbbus30*400*option2 )
```

in

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')

mdl.parameters.optimalitytarget=3


mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')

mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

print()
print("with more constraints")

option1=mdl.binary_var(name='option1')
option2=mdl.binary_var(name='option2')

mdl.add(nbbus40<=10)
mdl.add(nbbus30<=10)
mdl.add(option1==(nbbus40<=3))
mdl.add(option2==(nbbus40>=7))

mdl.add_constraint(option1+option2>=1)

mdl.maximize(nbbus40*500*option1+nbbus30*400*option2 )

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

Comment: Thanks! How would you do it with the Python API instead of docplex?

Comment: Why not having a look at the example miqpex1.py ?

Comment: I am looking at it. I don't really see how it is relevant or similar to this. Could you elaborate a bit more, please? Thanks